# How can I determine if these perl processes are malicious?

Tags: security, apache-httpd, perl, php, process-management

Our Suse Linux web server has been running quite sluggish of late and rebooting relieves the issue temporarily.

After some further checks, I found that the firewall is blocking some outbound traffic on strange ports, which appear to originate from a perl command...

netstat:

```
# netstat -nape | head -2; netstat -nape | grep 185.162.9.131
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45781       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65180      26829/fixit         
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45777       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65175      29159/epim          
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45783       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65182      26052/usel          
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45773       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65067      6265/usel           
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45782       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65181      5885/epim           
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45771       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65065      5529/epim           
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.1:45775       185.162.9.131:147       SYN_SENT    30         65161      26432/epim
```

lsof: shows that it is a perl command

```
# lsof -i :45775
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
perl    26432 wwwrun    4u  IPv4  65161      0t0  TCP apache.home:45775->hosted-by.eurohoster.online:iso-ip (SYN_SENT)
```

I was hoping pstree might reveal some useful information, but I'm still no closer:

```
# pstree -ap wwwrun
perl,5529 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,5530 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,5885 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,5886 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,6265 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,6266 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26052 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26053 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26432 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26433 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26829 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,26830 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040

perl,28459 \040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040\040
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can find out exactly what these perl processes are and how they are being started ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `perl script.pl` closes `script.pl` as soon as it has finished parsing it, so there's no simple dumb way to see what they're up to. You could still check what files they have opened via `ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd`, though. You could connect with a debugger to them, and try to dump the syntax tree, and that's not trivial to interpret, and I'm not able to test it now. But someone may pick up the suggestion. My advice would be to kill it with fire: take down the server.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear, I don't see any reason for a legitimate program to overwrite its command line arguments with spaces (assuming that it's your version of `pstree` which is escaping the `<space>` as ```\040``` -- if not, it's even stupider: they may have used ```'\040'``` while meaning ```"\040"``` ;-)).

Comment: Assuming wwwrun is the user owning your web server, and that that isn't anything it should run, you have an intruder.

Comment: I just spent a few hours cleaning up the web server, and updating Joomla while at it, and did find numerous extraneous php files which have been deleted.  I've gone over some php hardening methods, but still the firewall shows these pesky outbound attempts - which are thankfully being blocked by our firewall appliance.  There has to be some way to get to the source.

Comment: I tried the  ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd but that didn't reveal much that I could understand.

Comment: Replace your `/usr/bin/perl` binary (or whatever the `/proc/[pid]/exe` of those processes is) with a wrapper which saves its files arguments somewhere. 
On Linux, you don't even have to replace it, you can bind-mount it over. There are a lot of tricks that you can do -- but it will take a whole tutorial. Better just take the server down.

Comment: `/proc/pid/...` is dynamic and represents the named process

Comment: @mosvy you say "take the server down", do you mean power off the server?  But I need to get to the bottom of this issue.  At least our firewall is blocking the outbound mystery traffic, so I thought leaving it up will at least allow me to fix it.  I looked in `/proc/[pid]/environ` and saw `SHELL=/bin/shUSER=wwwrunPATH=/usr/bin:/bin_=/usr/bin/perlPWD=/HOME=/var/lib/wwwrunSHLVL=2LOGNAME=wwwrun` which made me think maybe I can lock wwwrun down by taking away it's shell.  Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: I have already given you a potential solution: write a wrapper which copies the file given as the first argument somewhere and the calls the real perl binary, and mount it over `/usr/bin/perl` or whatever `/proc/[pid]/exe` points to. Just as a process is able to overwrite its command line, so is it able to overwrite its `/proc/[pid]/environ`, so that's completely unreliable. And unless that's a honeypot, not a server with other real people's data on it, it's pretty crazy to continue running it connected to any kind of network.

Comment: @mosvy thanks for the ideas... I'll give it a go...   `/proc/[pid]/exe` does point to `/usr/bin/perl`.  I am not sure what you mean by writing a wrapper.  I have done a fair bit of basic bash scripting but this is new.  Do you know of any online reference that explains what you suggest?

Comment: I've never used it, but would auditctl be able to track and log what file the perl process is running?